# JSON Issue with API HREF

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

So i'm trying to get the href code to be a clickable button. So far i'm just trying to make it as a link!

Heres the code

```
$("table").append("<tbody><tr><td>"+title+"</td><td><a href='&quot;+href+&quot;'></a></td></tr></tbody>");
```

The JSON pulled back a `Href` link, All I want is to have a tabled button that says `link` and redirects the page using the link from the json.

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. create a button element
2. Attach a click event redirecting the page

```js
  var button = "<button class='redirect-button' data-url='"+href+"'>Link</button>";
  $("table").append("<tbody><tr><td>"+title+"</td><td>"+button+"</td></tr></tbody>");
  $("table").find(".redirect-button").click(function(){
       location.href = $(this).attr("data-url");
  });
```

Comment: Wow that easy?  TYVM!